# get list of ALL task-ids

Tags: redis, celery, flower

Using Celery 3.1 and Redis as my backend, I wonder if there is a way to get the 'history' list of tasks. I know that there is `control` api to get all `active`/`reserved` etc - but none of them have info about finished tasks.
I know that they are exist in Redis by running redis-cli:

```
localhost:6379> keys *
1) "celery-task-meta-2483218d-12b7-4364-ac68-57457806df61"
2) "celery-task-meta-8a5c8d5f-a93c-4e29-bfb4-01e483ccc0f5"
3) "celery-task-meta-472046df-025f-48ab-86dc-77fb746bef96"
4) "celery-task-meta-8819190f-bd64-4f67-9a4f-026e9d72bcc6"
```

My goal is to get the tasks status (similar to flower) for real-time tasks but also for history.

**EDIT:** I found that flower as api call: http://localhost:5555/api/tasks that return what I'm looking for. I'll look for the implementation..

Comment: `flower` works only with events. Once restarted it loses everything. You'd better use database backend. I had a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726948/celery-task-history

Comment: Thanks for your reference